# Error while connecting to IBM DB2 with Tableau Desktop?

Tags: linux, db2, odbc, tableau-api, rhel6

I'm trying to connect to a IBM DB2(v10.5) database with Tableau Desktop v10. When i enter the credentials and try to login, it shows the below error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

The DB2 database is available in a Linux machine(rhel 6.5).What are the prerequisites and odbc drivers i need to install to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download and install the IBM DB2 driver from Tableau's website at https://www.tableau.com/support/drivers.

[Tableau's online help](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_db2.html) includes a page for setting up a connection to DB2. I am abbreviating them here.

1. Start Tableau and under Connect, select IBM DB2. For a complete list of data connections, select More under To a Server. Then do the following:

   - Enter the name of the server that hosts the database and the name of the database that you want to connect to.
   - Enter your user name and password.
   - If Tableau can't make the connection, verify that your credentials are correct. If you still can't connect, your computer is having trouble locating the server. Contact your network administrator or database administrator.    -
   - Select Sign In.
2. On the data source page, do the following:

   - (Optional) Select the default data source name at the top of the page, and then enter a unique data source name for use in Tableau. For example, use a data source naming convention that helps other users of the data source figure out which data source to connect to.
   - From the Schema drop-down list, select a schema or use the text box to      search for a schema by name.
   - Under Table, select a table or use the text box to search for a table by name.
   - Drag a table to the canvas, and then select the sheet tab to start your analysis.

Comment: Thanks! I did that.